# Query recursively dataset and tables from a project

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new in Google BigQuery.
Somebody can help me with a query which recursively does a `select * from.....`

below a global view of my project architecture.

```
project
   |__ dataset_1
                |__ tab_1
                |__ tab_2
   |__ dataset_2
                |__ tab_1
                |__ tab_2
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this!? what number of datasets you have and average count of tables in them?

Comment: Hello Mikhail
I have 2 datasets under my project and 2 tables per dataset

Comment: and what would be the result? Do you want to UNION ALL output of those four tables?

Comment: I would use Python or similar scripting language to generate the query you are looking for.